# Как внести строку в массив?

Tags: массивы, php

Есть строка, типа "blabla,","","bla" ... "bla" - как ее внести в массив. Explode не подходит в силу разнообразных вариантов "blabla," поля могут быть

```
 "name1","name2","name3","name4"
 "name1",,,"name4"
 "nam,dcd,e1",,,"name4"
 "na\"me1",,,"name4"
```

Comment: Вы уверены что 4-я строка имеет место быть? Если это CSV то обычно кавычка экранируется как `\"`.

А есть могут быть значения без кавычек, просто через запятую, то тут подойдет несложный конечный автомат.

Comment: да поправил

Comment: Сначала подгоняем все регулярками и(или) str_replace'ом, потом - **explode** - PROFIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему не `explode()`?

Обрезать первую и последнюю кавычку в строке, а, потом, с помощью `explode()` делить все разделителем `","`.

```
$str = '"blabla,","","bla" ... "bla"';
$array = explode('","', substr($str, 1, strlen($str) - 2));
print_r($array);
```

**UPD:**
Набросал простенький конечный автомат для разбора:

```
<?php

$line = '"na\"me1",,,"name4","nam,dcd,e1",,,"name4"';
$ind = 0;
$arr = array();
$arr[$ind] = $line{0};
$in_str = ($line{0} == '"');
// посимвольный обход всей строки
for( $i = 1; $i < strlen($line); $i++ ){
    // переход в режима в кавычках или за кавычками
    if( ($line{$i} == '"') && ($line{$i - 1} != '\\') ){
        $in_str = !$in_str;
    }
    // если нашли разделитель за кавычками, то заполняем следующий элемент массива
    if( ($line{$i} == ',') && !$in_str ){
        $arr[++$ind] = '';
    }else{
        $arr[$ind] .= $line{$i};
    }
}    
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: просто строка разнообразная и там тоже может встречаться ,

Comment: Дополнил ответ кодом.
Я предлагаю не запятой делить, а последовательностью кавычка-запятая-кавычка.

Comment: Выложите пожалуйста несколько примеров этих строк. может быть там не всё сложно. Главное, что бы он а поддавалась шаблону

Comment: поля могут быть `"name1","name2","name3","name4"`<br/>
                `"name1",,,"name4"`<br/>
                `"nam,dcd,e1",,,"name4"`<br/>
                `"na"me1",,,"name4"`<br/>

Answer (score 2):

регулярное выражение на Perl выглядело бы так: /"(.*)",/ для одного выражения. На PHP незнаю, есть ли такой сплит. должен по-идее быть.